# How do I get the Ansible expect module to properly wait for pid file creation with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to start a bunch of services on a node with a service startup shell script we use. It seems like the services do not fully startup because ansible doesn't wait for the script to finish running (part of it starts `thin` webserver in the bg). I want the `with_items` loop to wait until the pid file is in place before starting the second srvc.

```
- name: startup all the services   
  hosts: all   
  gather_facts: no   
  tasks:
    expect:
      command: /bin/bash -c "/home/vagrant/app-src/app_global/bin/server_tool server_daemon {{ item }}"
      creates: "/home/vagrant/app-src/{{ item }}/tmp/pids/thin.pid"
      with_items:
        - srvc1
        - srvc2
```

I want the items loop to work both with the `command` as well as the `thin.pid` file it creates.

But it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it.

```
  vagrant provision 
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...
    default: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [startup all the services] ******************************************* 

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
```

Comment: Is that all in the playbook? Why are you using `expect` module if you don't specify any prompts and responses? Are you sure you understand the purpose of [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)? Sorry, if I misunderstood your intentions, but from reading the question I'm not sure what you ...expect Expect to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your intentions correctly, you shouldn't be using Expect module at all. It is for automating programs requiring interactive input (see: [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)).

To start services sequentially and suspend processing of the playbook until the `pid`-file was created, you can (currently) split your playbook into two files and use `include` module with `with_items` attribute:

Main playbook:

```
- name: startup all the services   
  hosts: all   
  gather_facts: no   
  tasks:
    - include: start_daemon.yml srvcname={{ item }}
      with_items:
        - srvc1
        - srvc2
```

Sub-playbook `start_daemon.yml`:

```
- shell: "/home/vagrant/app-src/app_global/bin/server_tool server_daemon {{ srvcname }}"
  args:
    creates: "/home/vagrant/app-src/{{ srvcname }}/tmp/pids/thin.pid"

- name: Waiting for {{ srvcname }} to start
  wait_for: path=/home/vagrant/app-src/{{ srvcname }}/tmp/pids/thin.pid state=present
```

---

Remarks:

I think you don't need to specify `/bin/bash` for `command` module (however it might depend on the configuration). If for some reason `server_tool` requires shell environment, use `shell` module (as I suggested above).

With `name:` in the `wait_for` task you'll get an on-screen info which service Ansible is currently waiting for.

For future: A natural way to do it would be to use `block` module with `with_items`. This feature has been [requested](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262), but as of today is not implemented.